# Add Constraint to navigationBar Programmatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to add constraint to navigation bar, I have `UIImageView`, which has width, height and is centered horizontally, I want to add vertical space between `UIImage` and `navigationBar` to 0, I'm trying this for like 1 hour and couldn't figure out how, i tried adding constraint to `UIView`, and added constant of `navbarHeight + statusBarHeight`, and it worked, but I want to make relationship between imageview and navbar

```
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(verticalSpace) // this works
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try with `topLayoutGuide`

```
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image,  
                                       attribute: .Top,  
                                       relatedBy: .Equal,  
                                       toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,  
                                       attribute: .Bottom,  
                                       multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

The above constraint explanation:

> simply its called:  **vertical space between image.Top & self.topLayoutGuide.Bottom = 0**

that means Top constraint of image view attached with a Bottom attribute of topLayoutGuide with constant 0.

You can use `anchors` as well to make this possible for `iOS 10+`

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
} else {
   image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked, but could you please explain differences between those two "attributes", one says .Top one says .Bottom, why is that?

Comment: i just realized this doesn't work when using outlet UIImageView, could you tell me why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104837/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-nikagar4).

Comment: when i create "let imageView" and add this verticalSpace, it works perfectly, but when i try to do this on @IBOutlet imageView it does not, i created imageview in storyboard so i can see whats going on and constraint doesn't work anymore, havent changed code, except instead of programatically adding imageview i addet it in storyboard

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 may you update your answer to reflect also post iOS 10 like Andy Novak's answer says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219283

Answer (score 10):

llkenny's answer for iOS 11.0+ :
`image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true`

Answer (score 3):

With anchors:

```
image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard. Two constraints:

[image]

The first:

[image]

The second:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image: UICollectionViewExample]
code:

```
func mainCollectionViewConstraint() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        mainCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        mainCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        mainCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    ])
}
```